# How Can Alter X Axis Values In MSChart toName of Months

Tags: c#, charts, mschart

I want to alter chart X Axis values to show name of Months

Ex : 1 => January , 2 => February , etc.

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlCommand s = new SqlCommand("ReportMonthly", SCon);
        s.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        s.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Year", Year);
        SCon.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr = s.ExecuteReader();
        dt.Load(dr);
        chtWRMonthly.DataSource = dt;
        chtWRMonthly.Series["Sold"].XValueMember = "Month";
        chtWRMonthly.Series["sRemaining"].XValueMember = "Month";
        chtWRMonthly.Series["Bought"].XValueMember = "Month";
        chtWRMonthly.Series["bRemaining"].XValueMember = "Month";
        chtWRMonthly.Series["Sold"].YValueMembers = "sTAccount";
        chtWRMonthly.Series["sRemaining"].YValueMembers = "sRemaining";
        chtWRMonthly.Series["Bought"].YValueMembers = "bTAccount";
        chtWRMonthly.Series["bRemaining"].YValueMembers = "bRemaining";
        SCon.Close();
```

and how can fix name of Months in the chart and then set their values ?

Example:

[image]

Comment: What datatype do you use for the x-values you add? Are they actual DataTimes?? Then and only then you can use a nice Fromtat string for the x-axis labels. Make 100% you don't add them add string!! Btw: The graphic you show looks too brurred I can't tell what is shows..

Comment: its just intiger value , no

Comment: but it's very clear , then what can i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately `MSChart` doesn't allow any real expressions, so I don't see how you could translate the integers to months directly.

There are various workarounds but which you prefer will depend on you..

1) modify the `DataSource` to bring back `DateTimes`or..

2) ..to bring back the month strings.

The latter will prevent you from working with the x-values.

3) Modify the `DataTable` to contain `DateTimes` ; this must happen after each retrieval.

4) replace the `Axis.Labels` altogether by `CustomLabels`.

---

Here is an example of workaround #3: It adds a new column ('dateX') to the table and fills it with dates calculated from `DateTime.Now.Date` **plus** the integer in a column 'c1'. The y-values are in a column 'c2'.

Of course **you** should use a suitable starting `DateTime` value, not the present date!

Note that you need to tell the databinding about the **type** of the `XValueMember` and maybe also of the `IntervalType`!

Finally you can format the new column to show the localized (German) month names..:

```
if (!DT.Columns.Contains("dateX")) DT.Columns.Add("dateX", typeof(DateTime));

foreach (DataRow row in DT.Rows)
    row.SetField<DateTime>("dateX", DateTime.Now.Date.AddMonths(row.Field<int>("c1")));


Series s = chart1.Series[0];
s.XValueMember = "dateX";
s.XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
s.YValueMembers = "c2";

chart1.DataSource = DT;
chart1.DataBind();

Axis ax = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX;
ax.LabelStyle.Format = "MMMM" ;
ax.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Months;
ax.Interval = 1;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

for Persian Months' Name

```
    Dictionary<string, string> MonthsDic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                MonthsDic.Add("1", "فروردین");
                MonthsDic.Add("2", "اردیبهشت");
                MonthsDic.Add("3", "خرداد");
                MonthsDic.Add("4", "تیر");
                MonthsDic.Add("5", "مرداد");
                MonthsDic.Add("6", "شهریور");
                MonthsDic.Add("7", "مهر");
                MonthsDic.Add("8", "آبان");
                MonthsDic.Add("9", "آذر");
                MonthsDic.Add("10", "دی");
                MonthsDic.Add("11", "بهمن");
                MonthsDic.Add("12", "اسفند");

///
private void LoadMonthlyReport()
{
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlCommand s = new SqlCommand("ReportMonthly", SCon);
            s.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            s.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Year", Year);
            SCon.Open();
            SqlDataReader dr = s.ExecuteReader();
            dt.Load(dr);            
            dt.Columns.Add("MonthName", typeof(string));
            foreach (DataRow d in dt.Rows)
            {
                switch (d["Month"].ToString())
                {
                    case "1":
                        d["MonthName"] = "فروردین";
                        break;
                    case "2":
                        d["MonthName"] = "اردیبهشت";
                        break;
                    case "3":
                        d["MonthName"] = "خرداد";
                        break;
                    case "4":
                        d["MonthName"] = "تیر";
                        break;
                    case "5":
                        d["MonthName"] = "مرداد";
                        break;
                    case "6":
                        d["MonthName"] = "شهریور";
                        break;
                    case "7":
                        d["MonthName"] = "مهر";
                        break;
                    case "8":
                        d["MonthName"] = "آبان";
                        break;
                    case "9":
                        d["MonthName"] = "آذر";
                        break;
                    case "10":
                        d["MonthName"] = "دی";
                        break;
                    case "11":
                        d["MonthName"] = "بهمن";
                        break;
                    case "12":
                        d["MonthName"] = "اسفند";
                        break;
                }
            }
            chtWRMonthly.DataSource = dt;
            chtWRMonthly.Series["Sold"].XValueMember = "MonthName";
            chtWRMonthly.Series["sRemaining"].XValueMember = "MonthName";
            chtWRMonthly.Series["Bought"].XValueMember = "MonthName";
            chtWRMonthly.Series["bRemaining"].XValueMember = "MonthName";
            chtWRMonthly.Series["Sold"].YValueMembers = "sTAccount";
            chtWRMonthly.Series["sRemaining"].YValueMembers = "sRemaining";
            chtWRMonthly.Series["Bought"].YValueMembers = "bTAccount";
            chtWRMonthly.Series["bRemaining"].YValueMembers = "bRemaining";
            SCon.Close();
}
```

//for Month's number and send to sql

```
    private void chtWRMonthly_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
string MonthName = "";
            Boolean S = true;
            Point MP = new Point(e.X);
            chtWRMonthly.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.Interval = 0;
            int X, Px = (int)chtWRMonthly.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.PixelPositionToValue(e.X);
            X = (int)Math.Round((float)chtWRMonthly.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.PixelPositionToValue(e.X)) - 1;
            MonthName = chtWRMonthly.Series[0].Points[X].AxisLabel;
            if (MonthName != "")
            {
                if (Px >= X+1)
                    S = false;

                SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter("ReportMonthlyShowInvoices", SCon);
                SDA.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                SDA.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Year", Year);
                SDA.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Month", MonthsDic.First(Pair => Pair.Value == MonthName).Key);
                SDA.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@S", S);
                DataTable DT = new DataTable();
                SDA.Fill(DT);
}
```